# Haskell stack script with a dependency from Github?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Is there a way to run a stack script (https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#script-interpreter) with a dependency from Github? I would like to run a script with the dependency somePackageFromGithub, so e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-18.0 script --package somePackageFromGithub

module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Hello World!"
```

Usually I would put this in the stack.yaml file as an extra dependency:

```
extra-deps:
- git: https://github.com/user/somePackageFromGithub.git
  commit: "some hash"
```

But the `stack script` subcommand does not allow to specify a stack.yaml file (v.2.7.1): `Ignoring override stack.yaml file for script command`. Is there a way around this limitation of the stack cli interface?